# Joomla Custom Category Blog

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.3

**I'm working in my own template using Joomla 3.3
and I've created a custom category blog in my template**

```
mytemplate\html\com_content\category
```

[image]
**now I need to make another custom category template, like news.php or products.php.**

[image]

**what I need is to have multiple custom category blog in my template. and I can select from menu manger the type of category blog template.**

[image]

**How to accomplish this??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue by a workaround.

In `mytemplate\html\com_content\category/blog.php`

I've added some conditional statements like;

```
if($this->pageclass_sufx=='x')
```

`echo $this->loadTemplate('item');//which is acts as blog_item.php
    elseif($this->pageclass_sufx=='y')
      echo $this->loadTemplate('custom');//which is acts as blog_custom.php that I'vecreated`

And in menu manager for the category item I add page class suffex 'x' or 'y'

Answer (score 0):

This is already a core feature of Joomla.  Simply go to the Module Manager and select any instance of the category blog module and go to the Advanced Settings tab.

The very first field, Alternate Layouts, will be a list of all the template overrides available for that particular module.

Hope that helps.